# What is wrong in the jquery code?

Tags: jquery

I have been struggling in fixing this code, wonder what is wrong at all...

```
var tips = "<p class="adobe-reader-download">Most computers will open PDF documents automatically, but you may need to download <a title='Link to Adobe website-opens in a new window'";
tips +=" href='http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html' target='_blank'>Adobe Reader</a>.</p>";


if($("div#maincontent a[href*='.pdf']").length>0){
    $("div#maincontent").children(":last-child").after(tip);
```

Comment: You asked this question earlier today or yesterday. Did you delete that question?

Comment: @cletus: i had not asked it, my brother was working on the same project, he might have asked, i don't know. I got the answer, thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using double quotes here at where it says `adobe-reader-download`

```
var tips = "<p class="adobe-reader-download">
```

Try this:

```
var tips = "<p class=\"adobe-reader-download\">
```

**Note:** If you use single quotes for your entire string, you won't need to escape double quotes.